# Ajax post script not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

This is doubtless a newbie question but I cannot find one that's similar. I want to pass a model to an action through a JS function. I have the Ajax script:

```
   var modelDataJSON = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))';

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Action1", "Home")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: modelDataJSON,
        dataType: 'json'
    });
```

And I have for the action:

```
  public ActionResult Action1(MyModel modelDataJSON)
    {
        return Content(modelDataJSON.ToString());

    }
```

It's not doing anything. What have I missed? Again, sorry for the newbie question but I have already been stuck for too long on it.

Comment: How are you determining that it isn't doing anything? There's no code that that would create a visible effect outside of the developer tools.

Comment: Have you checked the Console in your browser's developer tools for errors? Have you checked the Network tab there to see if the POST request is made? Have you added a `success` and `error` function so that something will happen when the response gets back?

Comment: But doesn't it call the Action1, which displays the content? Isn't that the correct script for calling an action?

Comment: "But doesn't it call the Action1" — How do you know if it does or not?

Comment: "which displays the content? " — No, it doesn't. It makes an HTTP response with some content in it. The browser might display that content but, given just the JavaScript you've supplied in the question, it won't.

Comment: So how do I start an action through a JS script? I read elsewhere that that was the correct way to start an action through JS ...

Comment: You do it like that. As I've said several times already, you've not demonstrated that it **isn't** working!

Comment: You just said that the JS I supplied won't display the action content. Now you're saying that that is the correct way to display the action content ...

Comment: What Quentin is saying is that there isn't enough code in the question to determine what the issue is. You'll have to show a complete example that we can try ourselves, otherwise it's impossible to tell what the problem is or if there's a misunderstanding somewhere.

Comment: I don't think any of the other code is actually relevant here. It literally depends on these two parts. Do you need to call a redirect function in success for the page to be displayed?

Comment: I don't know much about asp.net, but looking at the JavaScript code alone, as Quentin says, you're just making an AJAX request to the server, but **you're not doing anything with the response**. Where do you expect the content to display?

Comment: Perhaps there's a misunderstanding. What I'm asking is how you redirect to the Action1 URL using a JS script. If it runs then it will display the content because it's a content action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Perhaps there's a misunderstanding. What I'm asking is how you redirect to the Action1 URL using a JS script. If it runs then it will display the content because it's a content action.

Don't use Ajax if you want to load a new page.

To make a POST request, you need to submit a form.

The best way to approach this is to use a plain, regular HTML form and not involve JS at all.

If you really want to involve JS then you can generate a form.

```
var f = document.createElement("form");
f.action = myURL;
f.method = "POST";
// append inputs to the form to pass the data in modelDataJSON here
document.body.appendChild(f);
f.submit();
```

Note that you can't send a JSON payload this way (but despite the variable name being `modelDataJSON`, your Ajax would have been sending standard form encoded data anyway).

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot!